# How to create a Co-occurrence matrix between values and csv in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, find-occurrences

I have 5 values :
chr [1:5] "A", "B", "C", "D", "E".

And one csv table and one column in this csv file is "Letter" which some Letter contains the above 5 values.

| Name | Letter | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | A | 95 |
| Mary | B | 90 |
| Hannah | Z | 1 |
| John | H | 10 |
| Mike | C | 80 |

I wonder to create a Co-occurrence matrix to show the frequency amount of this 5 values mentioned in this csv file.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example? To me it's not clear what the question is exactly, but perhaps `table()` is what you're after?

Comment: what if i told you no one understands your question? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you! I have already re-edited it.